# Resolve pull push conflict in the protected remote master: Atom

Tags: git, push, atom-editor, git-merge, pull

I am using Atom. I didn't figure out how to make a merge request there, but I already have the pull and push conflicts.

How do I undo everything and start from scratch? How do I make a merge request on Atom? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution was to remove the project and clone it once again from the GitLab.

```
git clone remote-repo
git branch (to see local branches)
git branch -a (to see all of the available branches)
git checkout my-branch
```